# call strings by pointers in functions (syntax)

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that checks if a string is a palindrome, but I think I have some mistakes in using pointers for strings. What is wrong with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 1000

int IsPalindrome(char *);

void main(){
    int i;
    char *string[MAX], *string2[MAX];
    gets(string);

    for(; *string!=NULL; ++string){
        toupper(string);
        if(isspace(string)==1  || isalnum(string)==0 )
            for(string2=string; *(string2 +1)!=NULL ;++string2)
                *string2=*(string2 +1);
    if(IsPalindrome(*string)==1)
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}

int IsPalindrome(char *string){
    size_t p;
    static int i;
    p=strlen(string) -1;
    if( *string!= *(string+p-i))
        return 0;
    if(string>=string +p -i)
        return 1;

    else{
        ++i;
        return IsPalindrome( *(string+1)) ;
     }
}
```

Comment: C != C++ and this looks like C to me. In general, you should tag only the language you are compiling/writing. Also, seems like you are very confused about how to declare a string in C (should be `char string[MAX]`, i.e. without the `*`, since it is just an array of `char`).

Comment: You seem to believe that there is a problem with your code. There's probably a reason that you believe this. Would you mind telling everyone what that reason is? Perhaps it outputs the wrong value? Perhaps it fails to compile with a compiler error?

Comment: I'm going to guess it has to do with compiler errors: http://ideone.com/cIHWHZ

Comment: yes it fails to compile with a compiler error

Comment: Include the error message in the question. Also, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: I think you can [trim that down](http://pastebin.com/vRwpj7np) regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig what`s that?

Comment: @irani1995 - the code that WhozCraig suggested is using a second pointer that starts from the end while the string starts from the beginning and compares until all comparisons are equal and return true, or a comparison fails and immediately return false.

Comment: @alvits Exactly. Alternatively if a recursive solution is required (though I would *never* do this as such, its an interesting exercise) and you still want to avoid all those `strlen` invokes, you can front-load a recursive algorithm invoked internally, [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/ThMeefpx); the same idea (and a decent example of turning a tail-recursive algorithm into an iterative one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written as if sting type were char * so you should turn

```
char *string[MAX], *string2[MAX];
```

into

```
char buffer[MAX] ;
char *string = buffer ;
char buffer2[MAX];
char *string2 = buffer2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @marom has mentioned in his answer, you're treating `char[]` exactly as `char*` and it's not correct.

Here you can see your correct version of code. I've tried to describe it in comment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 1000

int IsPalindrome(char *);

int main(){
    char string[MAX];
    char *p=string; // points to last valid index
    int i, len;

    gets(string);
    len = strlen(string);

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if( isalnum(string[i])!=0)
        {
            // we keep just alphabet(in uppercase) and digits
            *p = toupper(string[i]);
            p++;
        }
    }
    *p=NULL; // terminate end of string
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(IsPalindrome(string)==1)
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}

int IsPalindrome(char *string){
    int len=strlen(string);
    if(len<=1)
        return 1;
    if( string[0] != string[len-1])
        return 0;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // we need to remove one letter from both side
    string[len-1]='\0'; // remove one letter from end
    //Notice we do above line as It's allowed to change the origin string
    return IsPalindrome(&string[1]) ; // send 2nd letter as start point
}
```

Ask any further question in comment section of answers or "Piazza" ;)